# How to monitor java process using cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Is there a way to find cpu and memory% of java process using cygwin?
I tried ps aux -W |awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'|grep PID,but the value is coming as 0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Java machine is NOT a cygwin program, it is a standard windows program so use a windows tool like sysinternals

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities

Answer (score 0):

Under Cygwin you'll need to use Windows commands.

For the basics, `tasklist /v` is fairly like `ps`.

For stats like CPU percentage, `typeperf` does the job, but its output isn't pretty!

```
typeperf "\Process(Java*)\% Processor Time" -sc 1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490960(v=technet.10)